# AES encryption in C

Tags: c, encryption, aes

I need to encrypt some specific string using AES and then update datbase column with the encrypted value. I already implemented the same functionality in java but for performance reason we need to implement it in C instead.
I am not familiar with C so I found the below example on internet,but I could not print the encrypted value.it is represented on a binary format.
http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt
How i can get the encrypted (String) value from the script example above?
Do you know some AES encrption C sample that I can refer to it?

Regards

Comment: See https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html.

Comment: You could use the PKCs#11 provider with NSS instead for larger strings. It even uses the AES-NI instructions by Intel if present. Switching to C for shorter values makes little sense.